# Codeigniter - form for resetting password

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter

I have a system consisting of a PHP API with Codeigniter and REST_Controller.

When a user asks to reset their password, the system generates a random number and embeds it in a URI that is sent by a mail to the user.

When the user clicks it, it calls a function in REST_Controller/Codeigniter that reads the embedded number and detemines, if it is valid. If yes, the user is presented with a website with a form to change the password.

Now, for the main question. When the user clicks the Submit button to send the new password, does the client side have to call another function in REST_Controller/Codeigniter? If so, how can I authenticate that the Submit request with data is from the user, and not a random reqest from the internet?

What am I missing here?

Comment: By using session , because to reset user need to be login.

Comment: Ever had of honeypots fields?

Comment: i think you need to validate the generated "random number" to verify it's the same as the one you have generated and sent in mail

Answer (score 0):

I just used the following approach:

1. The user clicks a link with a token embedded in the URI, that makes a GET request to a function PasswordRecovery1 that is run on the server, which verifies the token.
2. If the token is valid, a cookie is set on the client's machine with the user' ID and the same token that is sent back to the client's machine.
3. Then the user is presented with a webpage consisting of a password input field and a Submit button.
4. After providing a new password, the user clicks Submit, which makes a POST request to function PasswordRecovery2 that grabs the new password and then reads the cookie from the client's machine.
5. The PasswordRecovery2 function checks, if the token read from the cookie is valid, if so, it changes the password.

I hope that is a proper way of doing that.